# Functions that take quadratic residues to non quadratic residues

Tags: nt.number-theory, co.combinatorics, finite-fields, quadratic-residues

Let $p$ be prime and $Q$ be the set of integers $x$ mod $p$ so that $x^2-1$ is a quadratic residue. Let $Q^c$ be the complement of $Q$. If we don't consider $x = 1$ then these two sets have the same size. Furthermore, one can check $p(Q) = Q$ and $p(Q^c) = Q^c$ where $p(x) = 2x^2-1$.

I'm looking for some function $F:Q \to Q^c$  so that $F(2x^2-1) = 2F(x)^2-1$. It's possible to construct many such functions by "brute force", just writing down the list of elements and assigning values to it according to the relation. I'm looking for a cleaner formula.

Can you find a nice $F$?

What are some nice functions that take quadratic residues to quadratic non-residues and vice versa? It seems like $F$ should be a variant of one of those.

Comment: If $a$ is a non-residue, $x \to a*x$ is a function that takes Q.R. to non Q.R. and vice versa, but it doesn't mesh with $p$.

Comment: It might be clearer if the polynomial and the prime weren't both called $p$.

Comment: Also, I'm attempting the check of paragraph 1 and failing. E.g. in $\mathbb{F}_3$ we have $Q = \{2\}$ and $Q^c = \{0\}$ but $2\cdot 2^2 - 1 = 1 \not \in Q$ and $2 \cdot 0^2 - 1 = 2 \not\in Q^c$.